# Does changing the character set from utf8 to ascii improve consumed space of a CHAR field on mysql?

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `a_token` char(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `a_token_exp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_a_token` (`a_token`) USING HASH,
  KEY `f_seid` (`s_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `f_seid` FOREIGN KEY (`s_id`) REFERENCES `sessions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and I want to change the charset for `a_token` since we use only ascii characters using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE tokens MODIFY a_token CHAR(40) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

and the new `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `a_token` char(40) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `a_token_exp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_a_token` (`a_token`) USING HASH,
  KEY `f_seid` (`s_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `f_seid` FOREIGN KEY (`s_id`) REFERENCES `sessions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and then I run `OPTIMIZE TABLE oauth_session_access_tokens`.

This query should (I'm not sure) the size of the table for my schema:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Table",
      ((data_length + index_length)) AS "Size"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = "test"
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

but the specific table `tokens` always returns **49152** before and after the `ALTER TABLE`.

Can I suppose that even with CHAR and utf8, if there are only ASCII chars, then the field doesn't preallocate the space for utf8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes, switch to ASCII.

Looooong answer:  There are many aspects to this question.

- If the strings actually vary in length, use `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`.
- If the strings are fixed in length, use `CHAR`.  (40 sounds like SHA1, which is fixed length).
- If the string is always hex, use `UNHEX()` when storing and `HEX()` when fetching, then store into a `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` column of half the size (`BINARY(20)` for SHA1).  That saves 20 bytes per row for Ascii.
- For older versions of MySQL, and varying length, `CHAR` pads to the given length.
- For older versions of MySQL, `CHAR` with `utf8` would force 3 bytes per columns, wasting two of them for hex.  This is possibly your main question.
- If you leave it as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, consider what `COLLATION` to use.  For hex, any collation ending with `_ci` is probably appropriate.  (For Base64 text, `_bin` is appropriate.)
- 49152 bytes = 3*16KB.  This implies that you have so few rows in the table that 1 block is for data, and 1 block for each of the two secondary indexes.  Even if the table has exactly 1 row, the table will occupy exactly 49152 bytes.  Or 100 rows is likely to be that same size.
- 49152 bytes is insignificant these days.  Even with a million rows, the table's size is not likely to be significant.  For a billion rows, yes, study my points here.  (However, for a billion rows, another issue arises -- `INT UNSIGNED` overflows at about 4 billion.)
- SHA1 (or any other 'random' string) will have performance problems when the index becomes bigger than RAM.
- In the context of this question, `Ascii` and `latin1` perform similarly.
- (There are probably more things I could point out.  Most will be minor.)

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks for this long answer. Followup question on point 5: where can I find for which version MySQL stops forcing 3 bytes? Because what I'm try to demonstrate is that, in terms of space (not performance), switching from `utf8` to `ascii` doesn't gain anything. I tried the for a couple of hours without finding this information.
At application level it's always 40 chars and always ASCII.

Comment: I also suspect `ROW_FORMAT` is involved in this mystery by the way.

Comment: @dierre - I added a bullet item, and a possible version number of the change.  You _might_ be able to test the size via many rows of `CHAR(255)`, each with a single letter; compare utf8 vs. ascii`.  Also try with `REPEAT('x', 255)`.  At what point does Data_length go past 16KB.

Comment: I suspect you didn't save the comment, I can't see the new item. I will try to test the way you suggested.

Comment: @dierre The tip I've seen in the manual about utf8 padding to 3 bytes per character only applies to `CHAR`, not `VARCHAR`, and only in version MySQL 5.1 and older.

Comment: I tested it and yeah, data+index is always almost the same, sometimes utf8 is smaller, sometimes bigger (with `CHAR` on mysql 5.7)

Comment: @dierre - There are so many subtle things going on, that I am not surprised with "same/smaller/bigger".  It is quite tricky to devise a conclusive way to test the size of a schema or the speed of a query.  (My suggestion with `REPEAT` was designed to get you past a single block, etc.)

Comment: Yeah but that demonstrates that space is not relevant in the choice. Which saves me from a change in the legacy system.

Answer (score 5):

UTF-8 is a variable-length character encoding. For characters in the ASCII range, it only takes 1 byte per character. It only uses 2, 3, or 4 bytes per character for those characters that require it.

The wikipedia article on UTF-8 has a good explanation and an illustration of how the multi-byte encodings work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

So there's little downside to using UTF-8 even if you only have ASCII characters to store.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks, I was aware of how UTF-8 works, but unfortunately it depends on how MySQL actually implements it, which I was not sure about. As you can see from Rick's answer it seems depends on MySQL version.